# Lost my EU license and need to replace with UK license - help

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-citizens, driving-license

In a manic dash across a train station in London, I lost my wallet which included my EU driving license (issued in Portugal).
Since I'm a UK resident, I need to replace the lost license with the UK driving licence but the information on how to this is quite vague (I've tried a few of the .gov sites but keep going in a loop).

When I try to replace the license online, the site requires that the last license had a UK License (mine didn't)

If I try to exchange the license, the site tells me it's not necessary until I hit the age of 68

I seem to be stuck in a catch-22 with this.

Can someone advise what needs to be done?

Comment: @David You can only renew or replace an EU driving licence in the country you’re resident. Since she isn’t resident in Portugal, she may not be issued a new licence there. On the other hand, to get a new UK licence, she may need to send in her old one, which she obviously can’t do.

Comment: @MJeffryes Yes, you're right: I just missed that the OP was an expat. D'oh. I've deleted my comments.

Comment: Hi I just lost my EU driving licence too 2 weeks ago and I am in the same situation. Was wondering how did you work it out. Did you manage to exchange it with a British driving licence even though it's lost. I live here in the UK for more than 6 years and the licence lost was a German eu one.

Answer (score 4):

The government websites are poorly worded. In fact, the [page you found](https://www.gov.uk/exchange-foreign-driving-licence/y/yes/car-or-motorcycle/european-union) is saying after 68 you must exchange your licence, but up to that point you can do so voluntarily.

So you will need to fill in form D1, which has provision for lost driving licences.